# ERROR: Couldn’t connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run `docker-machine start default

Tags: docker, windows-10, virtualbox, docker-toolbox

I have a Virtualbox 6.1.4 with Toolbox 19.03.1 installed on Windows 10 with an user with administrator access.

I created a machine called xpto, then I run the eval $(docker-machine env xpto) to turn it active.

I have a docker compose file with two services (postgres and my application), when I try to run the docker-compose command I got the error below:

**ERROR: Couldn’t connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run `docker-machine start default**

I percept that the first service (postgres) start ok, but when try to run the second command happens the error above.

I did it in other machines and runs well, only in one machine it is happening.

What can be?